# div fullscreen (width & height) html/css?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fullscreen

I'm new into html/css things so let's get to the point.

I want to create a website with full screen  (width and height) even when you resize the browser or when you open the site using smartphone/tablet. I have 2 div (lets just say it "top" and "bottom") and I want only the "top" that got full screen width and height.

```
<html>
<head></head
<body>

<div class="top">
    <div>content 1</div>
    <div>content 2</div>
    <div>content 3</div>
</div>

<div class="bottom">
    <div>another content</div>
    <div>another content</div>
    <div>another content</div>
    <div>another content</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

or something similar with this http://scripteden.com/previews/Clean/

sorry for my bad english..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [swiper](http://www.idangero.us/swiper/demos/#.Vh2-GNKqqkp), working code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Swiper demo</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">

    <!-- Link Swiper's CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.idangero.us/swiper/dist/css/swiper.min.css">

    <!-- Demo styles -->
    <style>
    html, body {
        position: relative;
        height: 100%;
    }
    body {
        background: #eee;
        font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: 14px;
        color:#000;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    .swiper-container {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
    .swiper-slide {
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 18px;
        background: #fff;
        /* Center slide text vertically */
        display: -webkit-box;
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: -webkit-flex;
        display: flex;
        -webkit-box-pack: center;
        -ms-flex-pack: center;
        -webkit-justify-content: center;
        justify-content: center;
        -webkit-box-align: center;
        -ms-flex-align: center;
        -webkit-align-items: center;
        align-items: center;
    }

    .swiper-slide{
        display: block;
    }
    .top>div{
        display: block;
    }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Swiper -->
    <div class="swiper-container">
        <div class="swiper-wrapper">
            <div class="swiper-slide top">
                <div>content 1</div>
                <div>content 2</div>
                <div>content 3</div>
            </div>
            <div class="swiper-slide bottom">
                <div>another content</div>
                <div>another content</div>
                <div>another content</div>
                <div>another content</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Add Pagination -->
        <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
    </div>

    <!-- Swiper JS -->
    <script src="http://www.idangero.us/swiper/dist/js/swiper.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Initialize Swiper -->
    <script>
    var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
        pagination: '.swiper-pagination',
        paginationClickable: true,
        direction: 'vertical',
        setWrapperSize:true     // this will set slide wrap div full screen, and you can override flex layout
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Fiddler here: (http://jsfiddle.net/futurist/dztabt3v/)

**Update 1**

If you want only using in Mobile/Tablet, don't want to support old browsers, can use add `flex-direction: column/row;` to `.swiper-slide`  to keep inner div vertically/horizontally align, and set `setWrapperSize:false` to get better performance.

Fiddler here: (http://jsfiddle.net/futurist/nbvr1uLb/1)

**Update 2**

If you want scroll on bottom, just set a container div within bottom, and give CSS: `overflow:scroll;`

Fiddler here: (http://jsfiddle.net/futurist/nbvr1uLb/2/)

Comment: love it! but I have 1 more question, since I've got a lot of things in the 'bottom' and need to scroll it to see the content, can I use mouse scroll to see the rest of the contents?

Comment: sorry for the late reply, got my self caught on works..
It's very nice :D
and one more question, can I change the dots into something for example, a navbar?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what browsers will you be supporting but a simple way that will work for ie10 and above is

```
body {
  width: 100vw;
  height:100vh
}
```

Example : https://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/

Comment: mostly chrome and mozilla, but later I'm going to go for ie since I'm using wp

Comment: did you try the above?